# wp_editor adds escaped character

Tags: escaping, character

wp_editor adds escaped character like:

"/

```
for example: <p style=\"text-align:center\">text</p>

I want to make: <p style="text-align:center">text</p>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use wordpress Sanitize:

```
<?php wp_kses_post( $data ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_post

Answer (score -1):

Found my answer :)

```
str_replace(array('\"'), '"', "<p style=\"text-align:center\">text</p>")
```